# Menu dropdown isn't hidden beforehand

Tags: html, css

I've added submenus to some code I found online. I want the submenu, which is a drop-down list, only to show when I hover over the appropriate `<a>`. But the submenu is appearing right from the start without me hovering over it.  What am I doing wrong?

```css
div.menu3 {
  /*width:500px;margin:0 auto;*/
  /*Uncomment this line to make the menu center-aligned.*/
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
  height: 25px;
  *position: relative;
  *top: 1px;
  /*Hacks for IE6 & IE7 */
}
div.menu3 a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin-right: 1px;
  /* It specifies the distance between each tab */
  background: #F7F7F7;
  color: Black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: normal 12px Trebuchet MS;
  line-height: 24px;
  border: 1px solid #CAD0DB;
  border-bottom: 0;
  color: #666;
  vertical-align: top;
  /*ChangeSet#2*/
  text-decoration: none;
}
div.menu3 a:hover,
div.menu3 a.current {
  background: #E9ECF0;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: #000;
}
div.menu3sub {
  height: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #CAD0DB;
  background: #E9ECF0;
}
div.menu3sub a:hover,
div.menu3 a.current {
  background: #E9ECF0;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu3">
  <a href="#1" class="current">Home</a>
  <a href="#2">Employees</a>
  <a href="#3">Department</a>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Add Department</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Delete Department</a></li>
  </ul>

  <a href="#4">Asset</a>

</div>

<div class="menu3sub"></div>
```

Comment: Your html is off as well... You're not really grasping the essence of html and css combined.. Your primary items in your menu should be list items and your secondary dropdown should be an unordered list and you should target those elements. Some variation of this idea will work.

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail.. im new to this so its hard for me to understand

Answer (score 0):

Your html is off. So your dropdown won't display properly. Use un-ordered lists instead of what you have. This should point you in the right direction.

```css
ul.menu {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul.menu li.submenu ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
ul.menu li.submenu:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
ul.menu li.submenu ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#1" class="current">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#2" class="current">Employees</a>
  </li>
  <li class="submenu"><a href="#3" class="current">Department</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Add Department</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Delete Department</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#4">Asset</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: im sorry, but im extremely new to this.. 
can you please explain in more detail..

Comment: You need to have your dropdown menu nested within another div. So to make things simple i used un-ordered lists <ul> instead of divs. If you run the code snippet i posted, you will see the drop down function. You can copy and paste the css and html i wrote, and apply your own styles to it.